# Customize Twitter oAuth Login Page

Tags: javascript, iphone, twitter, oauth

I'm studying about twitter API and oAuth authorization.

In process of oAuth authorization, obtain user authorization, user authorize at webpage twitter provide.
Authorize URL : http://twitter.com/oauth/authorize?oauth_token=%@

1. I want to custumize login UI.
2. I tried one thing using javascript.

document.getElementById('username_or_email').value = 'userid';
document.getElementById('password').value = 'pass';

1. I succeed in modifying user id field, but I failed to modify password field value.

Thank you for your advice.

Tae-ho.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If u want to customize Login UI better u should go for X-Auth. Follwing are links for Iphone. In this case u dont need to use WEB Login UI.

http://aralbalkan.com/3133